# How to transpose in Snowflake without PIVOT/UNPIVOT

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, transpose

I have a table with JSON data as below

| Name | data |
| --- | --- |
| A | {"X":1} |
| A | {"Y":2} , {"z":"xx"} |
| B | {"X":1} |
| B | {"Y":2} , {"z":"xx"} |

I was able to flatten the json data and convert into a table as below .

| Name | Key | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | 1 |
| A | Y | 2 |
| A | Z | xx |
| B | X | 1 |
| B | Y | 2 |
| B | Z | xx |

I need to transpose the key and value into corresponding columns as below in Snowflake Stored Procedure.

| Name | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 |  |  |
| A |  | 2 |  |
| A |  |  | xx |
| B |  | 1 |  |
| B |  | 2 |  |
| B |  |  | xx |

Comment: You probably need a dynamic query for this task, if you need to generalize on keys/amount of columns.

Comment: If you don't know how many different `Key` values there could be, since a pivot or series of case expressions won't work for your usecase, I would question if an RDBMS like snowflake is the right place to perform this logic, since you can't feasibly store the results if the columns are determined dynamically on each run. As an example, pivoting in a pandas dataframe, like this, is trivial.

Comment: My Keys are Dynamic . This is what I have so far
`    
    with distinct_keys as (
    select distinct key from Table, LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT => jsondata) 
    WHERE NAME='A')
    select
    'SELECT * FROM (' ||
    '( SELECT NAME, VALUE, KEY from Table, LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT => jsondata)
     WHERE NAME= ''' || 'A' || ''') AS src ' ||
     'pivot (LISTAGG(VALUE) FOR key IN (' ||
     LISTAGG('''' || key || '''', ',') || ')))' as dynamic_query
     from distinct_keys;
 `
The result from the above SQL gives
    Name       X       Y         Z
     A             1        212     xxx

Comment: If you have additional information then please update your question, rather than use comments. Your question should contain the current version of all relevant information - so that someone can understand the issue by just reading the question and doesn't also need to read all the comments. Thanks

Comment: For dynamic keys I wrote this post https://medium.com/snowflake/dynamic-pivots-in-sql-with-snowflake-c763933987c

Answer (score 0):

To get a dynamic pivot I created a stored procedure that looks at the results of the previous query (like your flattened JSON) and figures out the columns to generate the pivot in 2 steps:

```sql
-- Pivot the previous query results:
call pivot_prev_results();

-- Find the pivoted table:
select *
from table(result_scan(last_query_id(-2)));
```

Full code here:

- https://medium.com/snowflake/dynamic-pivots-in-sql-with-snowflake-c763933987c
- https://github.com/fhoffa/snowflake_snippets/tree/main/pivots

The stored procedure looks like this:

```sql
create or replace procedure pivot_prev_results()
returns string
language javascript
execute as caller as
$$
  var cols_query = `
      select '\\'' 
        || listagg(distinct pivot_column, '\\',\\'') within group (order by pivot_column)
        || '\\'' 
      from table(result_scan(last_query_id(-1)))`;
  var stmt1 = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: cols_query});
  var results1 = stmt1.execute();
  results1.next();
  var col_list = results1.getColumnValue(1);
  
  pivot_query = `
         select * 
         from (select * from table(result_scan(last_query_id(-2)))) 
         pivot(max(pivot_value) for pivot_column in (${col_list}))
     `
  var stmt2 = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: pivot_query});
  stmt2.execute();
  return `select * from table(result_scan('${stmt2.getQueryId()}'));\n  select * from table(result_scan(last_query_id(-2)));`;
$$;
```